Co-author on papers after leaving academia
I used to do research at a major research institution and recently left academia to pursue a corporate job in a pharma company. I helped with some data collection and analysis for a study while in my previous role, but now, a lot of papers using that data are finally being published. Since I am currently working at a pharma company, I am concerned that if papers with my name are coming out now, somehow that will look like there is a collaboration/endorsement between my company and the research institution, when really this is just work I did at my previous job and my current pharma employer is not mentioned in the article. I'm not sure if I needed to notify my current employer about these articles. Are there any legal considerations of these papers coming out now while I'm working at the pharma company? I do not spend any time outside in my current role collaborating with my previous lab. This is all past work.

There are no ethical concerns in what you describe, but you should probably talk to your current employer about the situation so that they know you aren't currently collaborating.
If the papers list your former affiliation rather than your current one, it will help, though I'm sure you know that already.
There is an outside chance that your employer will object, and you might need to have some discussions about authorship. That would be a very rare, I hope, situation in which the employer objects to the content of the papers and it could lead to some legal maneuvering, but not an ethical concern. But talk to HR or whichever to assure them.
Since you added "legal" to your question, let me add that this would depend on what agreements you may have signed. Worst case, I think, is that you would need to withdraw as a named author, and have your contributions listed anonymously or similar. But that is for lawyers to work out.
One thought, though I can't evaluate its worth, might be to have an end date listed on your prior affiliation before your current employment, perhaps in a footnote.

It is very typical in my field (physics, engineering) that the affiliation used in author listing is the affiliation valid during the work).(Most journals have option for footnote attached to the various authors that then list something like  'current affiliation' .Thisl clearly implies the work done at prior place and that the current affiliation is merely to be able to contact the author.

It is probably safest to discuss the problem with the employer (or the relevant Human resources person, if this is a big company.) For one, the employer has to be reassured that the work was not done at their expense, while they were paying you money for working on another subject (or possibly a related one.) The employer would also have to sign off, if their affiliation appears on the publication.
If you decide not to discuss this with the employer, there is a chance that they learn about it otherwise. How probable it is depends on the level and quantity of the publications coming out, the activities of the employer, whether they follow the publications in the field, and whether they care at all. Anyhow, it is better to have a justification ready, in case they discover - even if you would rather avoid discussing the subject with them.
There are various options that one can encounter in journals: current affiliation with a note that "the work was while at X." or the previous affiliation with a note "currently employed at Y." and various versions and combinations thereof.

Well, not HR, more likely their IP lawyers. HR will be pretty clueless, and if there are no IP lawyers then there probably isn't an issue in the first place.

@JonCuster I don't know how it works in the US, but normally HR is the place where employees address all the questions - it is HR that decides whether they need a lawyer or simply a standard form to sign.


I am concerned that if papers with my name are coming out now, somehow that will look like there is a collaboration/endorsement between my company and the research institution

If you think this is the case, then other people will think so too. Therefore, this is a perceived conflict of interest. If you don't mention this connection and somebody figures it out, it will look even worse.
The way to handle this is to fully explain the situation in the conflict of interest statement, something like

Mickey Mouse is currently employed at Acme Pharmaceuticals. All of his contributions occurred before this employment and he did not provide any substantial input after his departure from XYZ University. His current employer has not participated in, reviewed, or endorsed this work.


There are absolutely no legal considerations. If the work was done prior to your current work, and the affiliations reflect this, this is not even worth the conversation with your manager.
Edit: it appears there are multiple downvotes, and I would love to hear some comments from the downvoters. What is your experience?
Throughout my career I have placed a number of students and postdocs into industry ranging from aerospace to biotech and pharma. We continued to publish manuscripts on which they received credit/authorship years after they left the group. I think the longest was five years.
All the authors had the affiliation held when the work was done (i.e. my University). I have never had to write these drawn out apologetic statements assuring the company that it was not a collaboration (nor have I ever read any like that in the literature). People are aware that if you are coming from an academic research environment, your credit/dissemination of work from that time does not just end the moment you change location, nor does it imply you are acting on behalf of the company when previously completed work is published.
Admittedly, I may be the one who was doing it wrong, but out of curiosity I texted some old friends in the Bay area, in active pharma R&D to ask if they had such issues while their doctoral or postdoctoral work was coming out, and none of them did either.
So I ask the downvoters to kindly explain what their concern is, and what is it based on.

Not a down voter, but I think the last phrase of the original ("this is not even worth the conversation with your manager") is probably an issue for some (even for me). I'd think it worth a conversation, just to head off any misconceptions.
